# increase performance for the following small code

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am uploading an excel file which is having 1000 records. In my database(mysql), some records are already there. Now after uploading the excel file, I am string those data in an array. For that I am using PHPExcel. Now, again I want to form a new array with those records which are not in my datatabase. For that I am using the logic like:
First converting the array(which is getting after uploading the excel file) into string. Then from string I am replacing the record, which is in database by a space. Then again I convert that string to array.
Code is like:

```
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
//array_shift($sheetData);

$string = "";
foreach( $sheetData as $val){
    foreach($val as $v){

        $string .= $v.",";

    }
}
$string = str_replace($res['email'],'',$string); // $res['email'] is from database
$ultimate_array = array();
$formatted_array = explode(',',$string);
    foreach($formatted_array as $fa){
        if(strstr($fa,'@')){
            array_push($ultimate_array,$fa);
        }


    }
```

I got the result but performace is very slow. Can you give me some solution so that I can increase the performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Profile it using a tool like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) or [xhprof](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to go to string and back.
Use [array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

```
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

// you may need this depending on the structure of your array
// array_shift($sheetData);

if (in_array($res['email'], $sheetData)) {
    unset($sheetData[array_search($res['email'], $sheetData)]);
}
```

Comment: One is glad to be of service ;)